# Showing only one type of land usage in map (Google Earth Engine)

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to make a simple visualization in Google Earth Engine. The goal is just to filter the mangroves in the ESA WorldCover 10m v100 map.

According to the documentation there is a band called 'Map' and a 'Class Table' with numerical values corresponding to landcover. In my particular case mangroves have the value 95.

I tried the following:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("ESA/WorldCover/v100")
                
var visualization = {
  bands: ['Map'],
}; 

dataset = dataset.first()
                 .select('Map')
                 .eq(95)
```

Fine, it works, but I get a B&W layer with mangroves in white. The **desired output** woulld be a map (the default map) showing only the mangroves. In short: a visualization filter not a binary mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By applying `.eq(95)` you, as suggested, create a binary image. To avoid you have to apply a `mask()`. See the difference:

```
Map.addLayer(dataset.eq(95).clip(geometry), {}, 'binary')
Map.addLayer(dataset.mask(dataset.eq(95)).clip(geometry), {}, 'mask')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/9b6a8c5086d0ac87ac5ef18092bd8971

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly. I found another solution that worked as well. I guess it is the same written in a different way:
 `dataset = dataset.first()
                 .select('Map')
                 .eq(95).selfMask()`

Comment: yeah the result is the same, it makes a different if you want to retain the original rastervalue (95) or not (0/1). If you believe the answer helped you it might be helpfull in the future to accept the answer

Comment: Hi @Jobbo90. Sorry! This is the very first question I asked in StackExchange and forgot to accept. Yes, it helped a lot. Thanks again!